# How to fix 'NameError: name 'field' is not defined'

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

In my attempt to create a class `dots` with the fields `n` and `xy` as shown below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class dots:
    n: int = 200
    xy: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)
```

I am constantly getting the error :

```
NameError: name 'field' is not defined
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

My operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, and the kernel version 4.15.0-58-generic. I am using Python 3.6.4

Comment: What is `field()` supposed to be? It does not seam to be defined/imported anywhere

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import [`field()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) to use it in your code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
```

Comment: Great, it worked -- I don't get this error anymore.
However, I got a new error 'NameError: name 'List' is not defined'. I followed the python documentation on how to create an empty list.

Comment: @Kathia you probably need to add `from typing import List`

Comment: @Kathia also, are you sure you are running `python 3.6`? `dataclasses` was only added in `3.7` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes, I just double-checked and it's ´Python 3.6.4´. I read somewhere that ´dataclasses´ can now work with this version.

Comment: Kathia is right, you can install a backport with `pip install dataclasses` in 3.6